# About the left adjoint of $f^*$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, ct.category-theory, homological-algebra, sheaf-theory

In lots of different cases (Verdier duality, Grothendieck duality, étale cohomology, ...) the very existence of a (right) adjoint to the sheaf functor $f_!$ gives useful information. (I'm going to ignore whether the functors are derived or not.)

As it appears, in many of those same cases, the functor $f^*$ also has a left adjoint, which seems to be denoted as $f_\sharp$ in some places. (Examples: [this paper talks about this in Grothendieck duality](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1501.01999.pdf) and [these notes talk about this for $f$ smooth](https://guests.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/gallauer/docs/m6ff.pdf).)

Beyond implying that $f^*$ is exact, which we already often know, **does this functor gives any meaningful information?** I would appreciate knowing anything about it!

Comment: In the derived world (that is for exact functors between presentable stable ∞-categories) the existence of a left adjoint to $f^*$ is equivalent to saying that $f^*$ commutes with arbitrary products. In general, the existence of $f_#$ is related to $f^*$ commuting with limits (for example, in motivic homotopy theory, when $f_#$ exists, then $f^*$ commutes with loopspaces, which is often very useful).